# Проблемы с поддержкой Python в Vim

Tags: python, windows, cmd, vim

Недавно начал пользоваться консольным Vim. Установил bundle, установил плагин YouCompleteMe, установилось все успешно. Но плагин не работает и при входе в vim я получаю: 
 **YouCompleteMe unavailable: unable to load Python.** 
И при попытке выполнить в vim, например :python print(1) получаю: 
**E370: Could not load library msys-python2.7.dll
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.**
Пробовал вручную прописывать путь к библиотекам пайтона:
*set pythondll="c:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs\python38.lib"*
В итоге получал похожие ошибки:
 **E370: Could not load library function__PyArg_Parse_SizeT
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.** 
**Дополнительно:**
 
ОС: Windows 10 
Python: 3.8 x64 
**Vim:version** 
[image: vim:version]

Все что находил в гугле не помогло:

- не совпадают битности vim и python
- нужно сделать ребилд vim`a (vim я специально не ставил, стоит vim
  который был по умолчанию и у меня нету билда)
- другие решения для gui вима, но мне нужно именно для консольного
- вручную прописать путь к python lib

Comment: как минимум, ошибка в том что ты пытаешься подсунуть **статическую** библиотеку python-3 в переменную предназначенную для **динамической** либы python-**2** т.е. нужно задавать `set pythonthreedll="c:\path\to\python38.dll"` (направление и количество слешей тоже стоит уточнить). после этого должна заработать команда `:python3 print('hello')`. Если YCM не заработает, то копай в сторону того, где погладить vim, чтобы он по умолчанию использовал третий питон, а не второй... и убедись, что YCM собран с ним же...

Comment: Прописал в set pythonthreedll="C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3\python38.dll". При попытке выполить команду python на этот раз получаю: E448: Could not load library function PySys_SetArgv

Comment: гугл говорит, что теперь скорей всего «не совпадают битности vim и python»... я бы проверил это ещё раз... и если ты уверен, что это не так, то как ты пришёл к такому выводу?

Comment: битность Vim`а я не нашел как узнать, но до этого у меня стоял питон 32 битный, потом я его удалил и поставил 64 битный и ничего не изменилось, но тогда у меня и путь к .dll не был прописан. Сейчас тогда попробую опять поставить 32х битный питон

Comment: Теперь E370:Could not load library msys-python2.7.dll. Еще устанавливал msys2. Что еще может быть не знаю. Голова кипит уже..

Comment: «битность» `vim`'а можно банально в каких-нить свойствах exe'шника посмотреть, хотя под win нормальной утилиты я для этого не назову... или, как говорит гугл, `:echo has("win64")`... по поводу ошибки, команда `:python3print('hello')` работает? по идее с ней vim не должен даже пробовать загрузить второй питон... если да, то как я раньше и писал, стоит поискать, где погладить vim, чтобы он использовал третий питон по умолчанию... со сторонней сборкой третьего питона под vim из головы идеи у меня кончились...

Comment: просто исполняемго файла vim`a как такового нет, запускаю его просто через консоль командой vim. А команда :python3 print('hello') по прежнему не работает:E448: Could not load library function PySys_SetArgv. В итоге получается если просто попробовать запустить команду питона через :python будет ошибка E370, или Е448 выше, если пробовать сразу запускать через 3 питон.
А :echo has("win64") выводит 0, так что полагаю установлена 32 битная версия, как и версия питона. Не знаю, что еще можно придумать. Может завтра на свежую голову удастся что-нибудь найти. В любом случае спасибо за подсказки

Comment: исполняемый файл всегда есть, если он запускается просто из командной строки, то он расположен по одному из путей в переменной `%PATH%`, но как бы то ни было версия судя по всему 32-х битная... по поводу ошибки мне сложно сказать, хотя, как человек, который свято верит в некомпетентность всего, что не было подкреплено выводами консольных команд, я бы настаивал, что что-то не так с установленной библиотекой, однако мне сложно предполагать что-либо о типовой установке vim'а в win, т.к. я взаимодействовал с подобной средой полтора раза, да и то это были портабельные версии на флешке...

Comment: насколько я вижу у вас `vim` собран со второй и третьей версией питона - я где-то читал что из-за этого возможны проблемы с загрузкой питона. Лучше пересобрать его с одной версией (2 или 3) python

Comment: вот сдесь почитайте: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source - там еще может быть проблема с именованием директории в которой лежать конфиги python